# ¿Cómo cambiar el estilo de un modal?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tengo el siguiente codigo CSS.

```
 .modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) url('/SISTEMAL/Images/ajax-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

Cree un dialog que se muestra al dar clic sobre un elemento de un jsgrid.

Quisiera cambiar el estilo de éste, ya que se la barra de titulo se muestra en color rojo, y me gustaría cambiarlo.

```
  <div id="detailsDialog" class="box-primary">
```

utilizo la etiqueta

```
     $("#detailsDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        close: function () {
            $("#detailsForm").validate().resetForm();
            $("#detailsForm").find(".error").removeClass("error");
        }
    });
```

Si alguien puede decirme como hacerlo se lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Hola masha. ¿Quieres cambiar el color rojo re la barra de título?. Deberías copiar el código html de la ventana modal también así te puedo ayudar.

Comment: hola @LucasAccastello ya acualicé mi publicación, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que he entendido en tu pregunta necesitas cambiar el color de la cabecera de tu diálogo.

Estos diálogos se generan con **jQuery**, por tanto ellos generan unas clases en el **html** del diálogo que puedes modificar con **css**. Te recomiendo con el **inspeccionador de elementos** de tu navegador revisar el código css de tu diálogo y poder modificarlo a tu gusto.

En este caso deberías de sustituir la siguiente clase:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar {
    background: #00BCD4;
}
```

Con esto verás que tu barra de título cambiará a un tono azulado.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, tu respuesta ha sido la solución a mi problema. Saludos.